# Unknown action [PostController@deletePost] using URL::action() in Laravel4

Tags: php, templates, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a beginner to Laravel. I've created a simple blog. In the page that lists the posts for the admin, i've put a `delete` link with the post id attached as a parameter.

This link is to an action called `deletePost`, Just wrote its declaration nothing more.

Whenever i access the route `public/admin/post`, I get this message :

> Unknown action [PostController@deletePost].

Here's my Controller class :

```
class PostController extends BaseController {

    public function listPosts(){
        $posts = Post::all();
        return View::make('admin.post.list')->with('posts' , $posts);
    }

    public function addPost(){
        $data = Input::all();
        $rules = array(
            'title' => 'required|min:3',
            'body' => 'required|min:10',
        );
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);

        if($validator->passes()){
            $post = new Post();
            $post->title = htmlentities(trim($data['title']));
            $post->body = strip_tags($data['body'], '<strong><pre>');
            $post->save();
            return View::make('admin.post.add')->with('message' , 'Post successfuly added.');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('admin/post/add')->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }

    public function deletePost($id){
        return $id;
    }

}
```

And my routes :

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function(){
    Route::get('/' , function(){
        return View::make('admin.main')->with('title', 'Main');
    });

    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'post'), function(){
        Route::get('/', "PostController@listPosts");
        Route::get('add', function(){ return View::make('admin.post.add'); });
        Route::post('add', "PostController@addPost");
    });
});
```

And finally the view that produces this error :

```
@extends('layout.layout')

@section('header')

@stop

@section('content')
<h2>Main - Admin - Post Main menu</h2>
<ul>
    <li><a href="{{ url('admin/post/add') }}">Add</a></li>        
</ul>

@if(isset($posts))
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <p>{{ $post->body }}</p>
        <a href="{{ action('PostController@deletePost', array('id' => $post->id)) }}">Delete</a>
    @endforeach
@endif

<a href="{{ url('admin/') }}">Back</a>
@stop
```

Comment: You didn't create a route for deletePost action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to set a route for the deletePost action. Assuming your url is `admin/post/delete/$id`, try adding this as a new line for your post group in routes.php:

```
Route::get('delete/{any}', "PostController@deletePost");
```

Instead of using `{{ action('PostController@deletePost', array('id' => $post->id)) }}` to build your URL, you could use `link_to_action()` helper in your view to build the entire anchor including HTML tags/attributes/etc:

`{{ link_to_action('PostController@deletePost', 'Delete', $parameters = array($post->id), $attributes = array()) }}`

Comment: Very nice, And thanks for the `link_to_action` tip, Pretty handy.